# fetch info from updated website google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

I was fetching some info from this [site](http://airesantiago.gob.cl/), using

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
```

and then extracting info from the html document, but now the site was updated and there is nothing useful (or at least directly usable) in the html... Can I still get info from it?

Comment: Why scrape their website? Contact them for an API endpoint or RSS feed. They'll be happier since they don't have to provide the whole page, and you'll get better data, and you won't be potentially abusing their website or violating their website's Terms of Service.

Comment: It's a government site, so they probably won't...